# How to handle multiple similar projects with jira

Tags: components, project, jira

I have multiple but similar client-side iPhone apps, managed as branches in git (all they cloned and periodically merged with master branch). So time to time there's global fixes/improvements that should be done in master. I'm migrating to jira to manage my projects. If I create different jira project for each, I don't know how can I handle global changes. Jira project components seems to be right, but I can't find how can I assign issue to particular component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed with creating one project named "iPhone" and multiple versions, giving them names like "Master", "ProjectOne 1.6" and "ProjectTwo 1.5".

Answer (score 4):

JIRA components are project-specific. So instead of having a project for each branch of your app, you would want to create a single project for the master branch, then create components for each branch (you could also consider doing it with versions in JIRA if that seems more appropriate).

Components are created in the JIRA Project admin interface. Once components are created you should be able to specify which components an issue in related to in the Create and Edit screens for an issue.

An issue can be part of more than one component.

I hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately, it seems that components doesn't support versions yet https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-3501

Comment: Nope, it sure doesn't. You didn't mention anything about your apps needing to maintain different version numbers.

Comment: @M.Y.: No, they don't. However, a simple workaround is to just prefix the versions with the component name - instead of 1.1, 1.2, 3.5 you get appA-1.1, appB-1.1 etc. It's a bit ugly but works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I like the approach of @Jason_Dean, but you should additionally look at the following:

- If you have an issue for which you know that it is relevant for all of your projects, you should define the issue for the global component.
- Then you should check (manually) for which project this issue has to be fixed. It is not easy to keep track. Then you should create sub-tasks for each project where you have to fix the bug as well. Close the bug (globally) only, when it is fixed for all relevant projects.
- Commit from Git on your Jira tickets. I do not know if the integration between and Jira works well, but we use the integration of Jira and Subversion, and that helps a lot.